# Differential of Stochastic process

Tags: calculus, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Given a stochastic process

$$Z_t = e^{4t} \int_0^{t} e^{-2s} \, \,dB_s$$

where $B$ denotes the standard Brownian Motion.

Determine $dZ_t$.

I tried to make use of Ito's rule, seeing that $Z$ is a function of $t$ and $B$ but I got stuck trying to find the derivative of an integral transform.

I thought maybe applying the product rule of Ito, finding

$$dZ_t = \int_0^{t} e^{-2s} \, \, dB_s \cdot 4e^{4t} \, dt + e^{4t} \cdot e^{-2t} dB$$

But I feel as if this can never be correct...

Comment: @saz, so could you show me the answer?

Comment: Okay, so $dX = 0 dt + e^{-2t} dB_t$. Also, $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = 0$. So Ito's formula comes down to: $dZ = 4e^{4t}x dt + e^{2t} dB_t$, which is exactly what I already had....

Comment: I fail to see why the integral cannot be there since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 4e^{4t}x$, now here the $x$ pops up and $x$ also has the integral.

Comment: Okay, it seems that I made a mess out of this, sorry about that. In your earlier (edited) comment I confused $X$ with $Z$ and therefore I thought that you went wrong. Regarding the answer at the end of your question (which you believed to be wrong): Actually it is correct (I got once more confused with your notation; sorry about that again).